# disable edit of cells of QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt6

The TableWidget gets its content, is sortable, etc. But by dblclicking the text in the cell becomes editable. Readonly is not an option, because then the whole table gets greyed out.

But how can I set editing of the table to disabled?

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton, QRadioButton
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon, QFont, QColor
```

in the window class

```
t = QTableWidget()
t.setStyleSheet('background-color:white;')
t.setFont(QFont("Courier", 12))
t.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
t.setSortingEnabled(True)

t.cellClicked.connect(cellclicked)
```

Comment: `t.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)`

Comment: Thanks. However... AttributeError: type object 'QTableWidget' has no attribute 'NoEditTriggers'

Comment: PyQt6 uses the full enum names, it's `QAbstractItemView.EditTriggers.NoEditTriggers` (or `t` instead of QAbstractItemView`, since it refers to a subclass).

Comment: Almost, but it works ;-) EditTriggger without the s...

t.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger.NoEditTriggers)

Thanks!